# Are there bands specifically dedicated to anime?

Tags: music

The example of the [Seatbelts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seatbelts_%28band%29), led by Yoko Kanno comes to mind. All of Cowboy Bebop's soundtrack was composed and performed by them.
Looking at their discography, their albums are all from the Cowboy Bebop franchise, except their live DVD. However, I am unsure as to whether they were created for this purpose, or if they were just a perfect fit.

Are there any bands that dedicate themselves specifically to composing and performing for anime? Or that may be created specifically for a certain series/franchise?

Comment: I know [I've Sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I've_Sound), but it's a music label, not a band and it started from karaoke music world, then Visual Novel themes performance and later anime openings and endings, featuring Lia and KOTOKO among their artists. A slightly different question could deepen this world however.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

Though they are not actually an actual and active band in Japan but [Houkagou Tea Time (HTT)](http://k-on.wikia.com/wiki/Ho-Kago_Tea_Time) (composing of the [K-On!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-On!)'s characters' voice actresses) were created for the anime's purpose itself. Toyosaki Aki (Hirasawa Yui), Kotobuki Minako (Kotobuki Tsumugi), Hikasa Yoko (Akiyama Mio), Satomi Sato (Tainaka Ritsu) and Taketatsu Ayana (Nakano Azusa) actually performed (sung while playing their character's respective instruments) some of K-On!'s OST live during two of their live concerts, [Let's Go](http://k-on.wikia.com/wiki/K-ON!_Live_Concert%3a_Let%27s_Go!) and [Come With Me](http://k-on.wikia.com/wiki/K-ON!!_Live_Concert%3a_Come_With_Me!!). The voice actresses were taught how to play their characters' instruments for the live concert so I think HTT was specifically created in dedication for the anime K-On!.